# How to apply conditional class in Razor

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, razor

I am adding class to `<li>` based on the current url.

```
<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                            <li class="@{string.Format(Request.Url.PathAndQuery.ToLower() == "" ? "active" : string.Empty);}"><a href="/">Home </a></li>
                            <li class="@{string.Format(Request.Url.PathAndQuery.ToLower().Contains("aboutus") ? "active" : string.Empty);}"><a href="/AboutUs">About Us </a></li>
                            <li class="@{string.Format(Request.Url.PathAndQuery.ToLower().Contains("research") ? "active" : string.Empty);}"><a href="/Research">Research</a></li>
                            <li class="@{string.Format(Request.Url.PathAndQuery.ToLower().Contains("contactus") ? "active" : string.Empty);}"><a href="/ContactUs">Contact Us</a></li>
                        </ul>
```

When I check the condition in watch, I am getting current class name "active" in visual studio.

[image]

But when I check in browser, class doesn't apply to `<li>`. I am sure that it is not override by any other code. Although If I apply class directly, it works.

[image]

Comment: why are you using `string.Format`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need change to `@(string.Format(Request.Url.PathAndQuery.ToLower() == "" ? "active" : string.Empty))` instead of `@{}`

```
<li class="@(string.Format(Request.Url.PathAndQuery.ToLower() == "" ? "active" : string.Empty))"><a href="/">Home </a></li>
```

Your code should like this with a variable for `currentUrl`

```
@{
    var currentUrl = Request.Url.PathAndQuery.ToLower();
}

<ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="@(string.Format(currentUrl == "" ? "active" : string.Empty))"><a href="/">Home </a></li>
    <li class="@(string.Format(currentUrl.Contains("aboutus") ? "active" : string.Empty))"><a href="/AboutUs">About Us </a></li>
    <li class="@(string.Format(currentUrl.Contains("research") ? "active" : string.Empty))"><a href="/Research">Research</a></li>
    <li class="@(currentUrl.Contains("contactus") ? "active" : string.Empty))"><a href="/ContactUs">Contact Us</a></li>
</ul>
```